# Rails slim "if" statements & nested tags

Tags: slim-lang

I have the following code in a rails slim layout:

```
- if content_for(:body_tag)
  yield :body_tag
- else
  body
```

The :body_tag template will typically involve something like `body ng-controller='myAngularAppController'`, for example

The problem is that any subsequent commands I make won't be nested inside the body tag. If I write

```
- if content_for(:body_tag)
  yield :body_tag
- else
  body
.container
...
```

The `body` tag will close before the container starts. If I write

```
- if content_for(:body_tag)
  yield :body_tag
- else
  body
    .container
  ...
```

The container wont render at all when a `:body-tag` is specified.

I'm assuming this is a common problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: So the contents of the body will always be the same but you need for the `body` tag to be dynamic based on the presence/absence of `:body_tag`, correct?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yes, correct

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing that's going to be dynamic on the `body` is the `ng-controller` attribute, I would recommend accomplishing it like this:

```
body ng-controller=content_for(:controller)
```

Instead of specifying the entire tag with the `:body_tag` identifier, just specify the `body` tag statically (because that *is* static) and the dynamic controller you want to use with a `:conroller` (or whatever you want to call it) identifier.